# All text in listbox to a specific location in MS Word Document

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am trying to transfer all the text in listbox to a particular place in MS Word Document, similar to bookmark. I've also tried doing a style in bookmarked but only the first line is showing.

The problem that I have is that I need to transfer the contents of a ListBox to the Word doc and have not got a clue how to do it.

Please kindly help if you can.

Here's my code.

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Public Class Form1
    #Region "dim"
        Dim exeDir As New IO.FileInfo(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.FullName)
        Dim WPath = IO.Path.Combine(exeDir.DirectoryName, "SampleReceipt.doc")
        Dim Word As Word.Application
        Dim Doc As Word.Document
    #End Region

    Private Sub NAR(ByVal o As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o)
        Catch ex As Exception
            o = Nothing
        Finally

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Word = New Word.Application
            Word.Visible = True
            Doc = Word.Documents.Open(WPath)
            Word.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("txtDate").Select()
            Word.Selection.Text = (TextBox1.Text)
            Word.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("txtSchoolYear").Select()
            Word.Selection.Text = (TextBox2.Text)
            Word.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("txtr1").Select()
            Word.Selection.Text = List1.Text
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        List1.Items.Add("string1")
        List1.Items.Add("string2")
        List1.Items.Add("string3")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a string from the items in a ListBox, just use the following function

```
Private Function GetListBoxStrings() As String
    Dim tempString As String = ""
    For Each line As String In List1.Items
        tempString = tempString & line
    Next
    Return tempString
End Function
```

and use it liike so

```
Word.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("txtr1").Select()
Word.Selection.Text = GetListBoxStrings()
```

Comment: Hey David! Thank you so much for this! The code works. I was able to figure it out by doing this as well. 


Dim lngListCount As Long
For lngListCount = 0 To List1.Items.Count - 1
Word.Selection.InsertBefore(Text:=List1.Items(lngListCount) & vbCrLf)
Word.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("txtr1").Select()
Next

But yours is much clearer. Thanks again!

Comment: ! Hello again good sir! I was wondering if how can i include vbTab to be included on the word document?